# Jasper report export pdf file content was duplicated

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody
void example(@RequestParam(value = "url") String url, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
    try {
        File reportFile;
        reportFile = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("example.jasper"));
        JasperHelper.printReport("pdf", reportFile, parameters, this.dataSourceMNG.getConnection(), response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    File reportFile = new File("");
    try{
        reportFile = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("example.jasper"));
        JasperHelper.printReport("pdf", reportFile, parameters, this.dataSourceMNG.getConnection(), response);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void printReport(String exportType, JasperReport jasperReport, String fileName, Map parameters, JRDataSource dataSource, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 6) + exportType;
        response.setContentType("application/" + exportType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        if (exportType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } else if (exportType.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
            JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } else if (exportType.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) {
            JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } else if (exportType.equalsIgnoreCase("rtf")) {
            JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));
            exporter.exportReport();
        }
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JasperHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English. I have a button click, when I clicked button will execute example method. It will call printReport twice and export to one pdf file. But when open the pdf file have 3 page, when I opened on microsoft edge It show first page, when open it on chrome it show 2 end page. I don't know why the problems is? How cal solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to check both *pdf* files in viewer (Adobe, for example)?

Comment: @AlexK: adobe show content like chrome

Comment: Seems to me that this is not issue related to programming

Comment: I call printReport twice at one button click for 2 report. I think content was overrided but cannot view all content.

Comment: @AlexK Can you help me